# Sending SMS in background from service while phone is sleeping -> RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE

Tags: android, sms, android-service, gsm

I'm developing a GPS tracking app which sends geo-positions by SMS in certain conditions (time, distance).

It works well, but when there is no GSM activity for some minutes (e.g. receiving SMS or phone calls), sending SMS fails with `SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE`. It is not a problem of bad signal, this even happens in areas where the signal is contineously strong.

For me it seems like my phones (Android 2.3 and 4.0.4) put the sending hardware to some kind of sleep mode after several minutes when the screen is off and even when I call `SmsManager.sendTextMessage` Android doesn't awake them.

Weird: when I receive an (unanswered) phone call or SMS, sending SMS works (I retry it every 2 minutes in case of certain errors). Often it is sufficient to unlock the screen without doing anything.

Is there a workaround? Can I tell Android to wake up GSM before sending SMS?

(I haven't tried `PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` because CPU is running obviously.)